# Improve Protobuf Performance using Any type

Tags: protocol-buffers, scalapb

Does using the protobuf Any time improve performance? Currently, I have a couple of services that just pass data through without doing any transformations. Would using the Any type save on cpu cycles spent serializing/deserializing data?

Comment: You may also be interested in [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/).

Comment: PB main page: "... mechanism for serializing _structured data_".  You "just pass data without any transformations". Why are you looking for any kind of wire encoding at all? Just send the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packing a message inside an `Any` will prevent the intermediate services that just pass it through from packing and unpacking it. Roughly speaking, if the time it takes to serialize+deserialize this message is larger than what it takes to serialize+deserialize an Any containing that message, then you may be able to save some CPU time, though I would suggest to measure first.